# Qt GroupedDragging crashes

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt 5.7 under MacOS Sierra, and I was experimenting with Qt's `GroupedDragging` in docks. However, this crashes my app a lot when I'm moving my docks around. It's quite random so I cant reproduce the error.

This is how I set my dock options:

```
setDockOptions(DockOptions( QMainWindow::GroupedDragging) );
```

I already tried enabling and disabling animations, tabbedDocks, etc, nothing seems to work.

Is there anything I can do?

This is the stacktrace:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   org.qt-project.QtWidgets        0x0000000102209fbd     QLayout::activateRecursiveHelper(QLayoutItem*) + 13
1   org.qt-project.QtWidgets        0x0000000102209ff8  QLayout::activateRecursiveHelper(QLayoutItem*) + 72
2   org.qt-project.QtWidgets        0x0000000102208f76 QLayout::activate() + 102
3   org.qt-project.QtWidgets        0x00000001022282a6 QWidget::setVisible(bool) + 678
4   org.qt-project.QtWidgets        0x0000000102341fcf QMainWindowLayout::animationFinished(QWidget*) + 2447
5   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000010307f923 QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) + 883
6   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x0000000102e70562 QAbstractAnimationPrivate::setState(QAbstractAnimation::State) + 578
7   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x0000000102e6f223 QAbstractAnimation::setCurrentTime(int) + 387
8   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x0000000102e6f058 QAnimationTimer::updateAnimationsTime(long long) + 104
9   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x0000000102e6db67 QUnifiedTimer::updateAnimationTimers(long long) + 295
10  org.qt-project.QtCore           0x0000000102e6ffec QAnimationDriver::advance() + 28
11  org.qt-project.QtCore           0x0000000103078980 QObject::event(QEvent*) + 48
12  org.qt-project.QtWidgets        0x00000001021e8edd QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) + 269
13  org.qt-project.QtWidgets        0x00000001021eb822 QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 5906
14  org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000010304eaa4 QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) + 164
15  org.qt-project.QtCore           0x00000001030a2ee6 QTimerInfoList::activateTimers() + 1142
16  libqcocoa.dylib                 0x00000001056db932     QCocoaEventDispatcherPrivate::activateTimersSourceCallback(void*) + 18
```

Comment: Post the stack trace, it's impossible to say without it.

Comment: @MrEricSir done

Comment: Did you try to set a breakpoint at "C++ exception" in Qt Creator?